# JToolbar is hidden by JMenu

Tags: java, macos, swing, netbeans, jtoolbar

I'm using Netbeans to add a JToolbar to my window which also has a JMenuBar. Here is the design-time look:
[alt text http://www.theinfernals.org.uk/misc/design.png](http://www.theinfernals.org.uk/misc/design.png)

.. but during run-time I get this:

[alt text http://www.theinfernals.org.uk/misc/runtime.png](http://www.theinfernals.org.uk/misc/runtime.png)

With the toolbar seemingly partially hidden under the menu names. This is on the Mac, btw. Is there something stupid I've forgotten to do or some layout trick I should be using?

EDIT: I'll add that the area below the toolbar is a SplitContainer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the problem might actually be that the toolbar object is not unber the menu(which is highly unlikely since the menubar is not part of the content pane of a frame), but too small. You can simply use setMinimalSize on the toolbar object after initComponents() or set a minimum size for the toolbar in the component's preferences in Matisse.